# Is all our Salesforce data Encrypted At Rest in various Orgs?

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield

We are going through a thorough security audit and I cannot get a straight answer from Salesforce, just boilerplate with lots of sales jargon.
Due to acquisitions, we have lots of Orgs.

- In our orgs which 1) are not on Hyperforce, and 2) have purchased no
  Shield products ("out of the box" orgs), is all of our data encrypted
  at rest?
- In orgs which 1) are not on Hyperforce, and 2) have
  purchased Salesforce Shield, and 3) have purchased and enabled
  Platform Encryption, is all of our data encrypted at rest? (I
  understand that selected fields are encrypted at rest.)
- In orgs on Hyperforce, I read that all our data is encrypted at rest. Is that correct?

For this purpose, it does not matter whether encryption is 128-bit, 256-bit or other, and it doesn't matter whether the encryption is probabilistic or deterministic, and it doesn't matter if encryption is volume-level or some other level, and it doesn't matter who manages or supplies the keys. (Yes, these things matter to us, but they aren't part of this audit. Maybe I shouldn't say "thorough".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperforce provides volume-level encryption for data at rest, as stated on [Hyperforce FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388902&type=1) and at page 9 of [Hyperforce Security Privacy and Architecture](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/misc/hyperforce-security-privacy-and-architecture.pdf).

---

> In orgs which 1) are not on Hyperforce, and 2) have purchased Salesforce Shield, and 3) have purchased and enabled Platform Encryption, is all of our data encrypted at rest?

No, it isn't enought. Please refer to [Salesforce Shield Platform
Encryption Implementation
Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf) (page 23):

> Why Bring Your Own Key?
> Shield Platform Encryption’s Bring Your Own Key (BYOK) feature gives you an extra layer of protection
> if there is unauthorized access to critical data. [...]
> **After you’ve set up your key material, you can use Shield Platform Encryption as you normally would to encrypt data at rest in your Salesforce org.**

Moreover [Shield Platform Encryption Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_best_practices.htm&type=5) states:

> **Existing field and file data is not automatically encrypted when you turn on Shield Platform Encryption**. To encrypt existing field data, update the records associated with the field data. This action triggers encryption for these records so that your existing data is encrypted at rest. To encrypt existing files or get help updating other encrypted data, contact Salesforce.

So to have your data encrypted at rest you need either Hyperforce or Salesforce Shield.

Comment: Thanks! I interpreted the "Best Practices" section that you quote to mean that (without Hyperforce) the fields we selected for encryption would be encrypted when we update those records, and, the fields that we did not select for encryption would remain un-encrypted at rest. Is that how you understand it?

Comment: @ElHombre55 yes, only the fields selected for encryption would be encrypted at the rest. It is meant for sensitive data (PII) and to be compliant with certain regulamentation, like GDPR or HIPAA

Answer (score 1):

Further inquiries with Salesforce led to a meeting with a person with more knowledge of internals. The result of that meeting: every Salesforce data volume is encrypted at rest, with one password. Users never need the password, the encryption is transparent to any process that isn't internal to Salesforce. But an attack using physical access or low-level access (such as malware in the disk controller firmware) to copy the data volume would be futile without that password.